# Strange behaviour of Safari's reader mode

Tags: html, safari

I built my website (actually, webpage) using a template and HTML+CSS+JS. This is the result:

https://vigibos.webs.upv.es/

When browsing it in Safari (on iOS) and turning on the 'reader mode', I get a strange result: some parts are missing, and the text is wrongly formatted.

These two images show how the webpage is rendered by Safari on iOS 12.3.1, WITHOUT and WITH the 'reader only' mode:

[image]     [image]

The 'reader only' version misses much of the content of the website, and is not coherent with the heading sizes: "Advised PhD & Master's thesis" and "Publications" should be the same size and aspect, since both are 'H3' headers.

**What kind of issue/error should I be looking for in the HTML code in order to fix this??**

Other 'textifiers' (such as some Google Chrome extensions) render the webpage quite correctly. So, maybe, there is no error in the HTML code, and the browser is interpreting the HTML code wrongly. **Are you aware of this behaviour of Safari's 'reader mode' in other situations?**

Answer (score 2):

Within the `div#main`, it seems each subheading is within a `section` and a `div`. Removing those containers and having the content directly under `div#main` seems to fix things.

[image: Screenshot of running Safari's reader on the fixed version]

> The section element represents a generic document or application section…The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element’s contents would be listed explicitly in the document’s outline.
>
> — http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element

I wouldn't wrap sub-sections of my content with `<section>` since markup-wise the headings are indications of sectioning enough and `<section>` and it feels like `<section>` was designed with other intents. If you need to wrap them for styling though, using `<div>` feels more appropriate although I'm not sure if that'll work with Safari's Reader mode.

### Original

```html
<div id="main">

    <!-- \\  About  \\ -->

        <section id="about" class="">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>About &amp; contact</h3>
                <p>…</p>
                <ul class="feature-icons">…</ul>
            </div>
        </section>

    <!-- \\  Positions  \\ -->

        <section id="positions" class="inactive">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>Academic positions</h3>
                <ul>…</ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        …
</div>
```

### New

```html
<div id="main">

    <!-- \\  About  \\ -->

    <h3>About &amp; contact</h3>
    <p>…</p>
    <ul class="feature-icons">…</ul>

    <!-- \\  Positions  \\ -->

    <h3>Academic positions</h3>
    <ul>…</ul>

    …
</div>
```

### See also

- https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader
- https://medium.com/@mandy.michael/building-websites-for-safari-reader-mode-and-other-reading-apps-1562913c86c9

Comment: The question's use of sectioning seems in-line with the intended use. I'd argue this is a bug in Safari iOS reader mode. (I have the same issue with pages that have several sections within an article -- it seems to pick out the largest section.)

Answer (score 0):

That's true that the simpler markup is the better the page looks in the reader mode (the markup should be semantically correct of course).
But I also agree, that sections here looks correct.

Since there are no official documentation, and we can only guess and collect random facts from trials and errors, I could only assume how it works.

I think the problem here could be because the op is using IDs instead of tags and classes:
`<main>`, `<header>`, etc

In my case, wrapping the content which should be displayed into  helped

[Here more details](https://www.client9.com/designing-html-for-safari-reader-mode/)